Is the fatty material found in the abdomen of farmed white fish comparable in Omega 3 content to farmed oily fish?
We are advised to eat oily fish.  For example the UK government advises "that people should eat at least two portions of fish a week, of which one should be oily".  A commonly available oily fish is farmed salmon.  My understanding is that this is because the fats in these fish is good for us, particularly the Omega 3 unsaturated fats.
Also commonly available is farmed white fish, for example sea bass.  This frequently comes with a large amount of fatty mass in the abdomen, both in loose structures around the guts as seen in the below picture and in a layer attached to the inside of the ribs.  In this particular case the liver was also fatty as evidenced by the white colour visible in this image.  When left overnight it releases a clear lipid.  I assume it is related to the feeding regime of the farming practice.
Is this fat good for you in the same way that farmed oily fish such as salmon is?

Image of removed guts here.
This post is principally prompted by government advice, as quoted above for the UK and here for the US.  The latter is more explicit about the mechanism:

Why eat fish? Several studies have shown that eating fish reduces risk of heart disease. Fish is an excellent source of protein and many species  are also rich in omega-3 fatty acids, particularly the long chain omega-3's EPA and DHA.  Consuming these long chain omega 3's reduces blood clots, triglycerides and arrhythmias (irregular heartbeats). Eating at least 250 mg of these omega 3's per day is enough to provide health benefits.

The protein content seems less relevant, as this can be had from many cheaper sources, so I thought the focus on oily fish was in large part due to the long chain omega-3's.  My understanding is that wild animals with their slower growth rate are particularly good sources of the longer chain omega 3's, so it seems a good point of comparison would be farmed salmon, an oily fish that is widely available and a similar price to farmed bass.
I can find salmon and catfish here from Sugata et al. though with difficult units, and this gives Cod liver Oil as 19% epa + dha.  That references the USDA, which might be this but I cannot decipher it.
It seems quite plausible that the abdominal fat of these fish is rich in omega 3's such that eating white fish is similarly health as oily fish, as long as one eats the abdominal fat and/or liver.  However I cannot find the relevant figures for this fish to make that determination.  Are they available?

I'm not getting the premise of this post - to me it seems as if Omega-3 fatty acid is associated with "healthy". That's been  accepted for a long time. However it's unsupported to the same extent it was by various meta studies on Omega-3 (especially on it's own). Can you substantiate that there's another source of "healthy" stuff in the fish, or is this based solely on the assumption I mentioned?

@JiminyCricket. I have added some content that trys to describe my premise.  Does it make more sense to you?

That helps yes. I'd caution you (at the risk of getting myself on another watchlist) that the US (or any) government may not be the most reliable source. Original research papers (with no  nasty affiliations funding the research) would be a better choice.

I don't see how the composition of abdominal fat in certain fish species is on topic here. That's particularly true since the motivation for the question is nutrition, which is explicitly off topic here unless related to medical treatment. The logical place for this question seems to me to be Biology.SE. Unless someone can convince me this is on topic here, I will migrate it to Biology.

@CareyGregory That seems reasonable to me.
